# How can I switch between views from one action in a controller

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework

I'm building a job site where you have two types of users who sign in i.e job seekers and prospective employers. Now both create their accounts from different sign up pages however they sign in from the same login form and are redirected to their account pages. The thing is that the base account page for each should be different5 obviously however I need it to point under the exact same url i.e `www.mysite.com/my-account`

What would be the best way to do it, is it possible to choose from within a controllers action what view to use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can render a different view inside the controller with `$this->render('path/to/view.phtml');`

A cool way could be in the init of your controller you set a different base path for the view according to the type of account `$this->view->setBasePath('/path/to/account/type/');` So you don't need to call $this->render(); but the render directly will look into the right folder, if you have one folder per account type